# Why does the Visual Studio Toolbox display empty?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, toolbox

It used to be that when I launched the Toolbox in Visual Studio, it would show all the UI controls available (based on whether the project is of type WinForms or WPF).

In Visual Studio 2019, the Toolbox displays **empty**, and then I have to do a right-click and select 'Choose Items...' and go through the tedious task of selecting the controls from the 'Choose Toolbox items' dialogue.

Every. Single. Project. Every. Single. Time.

How can I get the original behavior so that it displays pre-populated?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The toolbox is generally empty if no designer is open. Does it stay empty if you open a WPF or Winforms design view?

Comment: @PMF Yes, it is always empty, with or without the designer open.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the default environment and services by running the Visual Studio IDE in safe mode.

```sh
devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

If it works, load the default settings of the Visual Studio IDE:

```sh
devenv.exe /ResetSettings
```

`devenv.exe` is located in the following directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE`.

If `devenv.exe` isn't included in the *system path*, it can be run as follows:

```sh
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /SafeMode
```

---

###### References

- <sub>[/SafeMode (devenv.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022)</sub>
- <sub>[/ResetSettings (devenv.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/resetsettings-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022)</sub>

Comment: I experienced other problems when I started in safe mode.  FYI.